# How can I recieve Firebase Notifications on a Python Client?

Tags: android, python, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, pyfcm

I want to send a message from an android device to a device running python code. I don't want to implement a server for complete FCM Messages but instead use the "server-less" Notifications. Any way to do this without setting up my own FCM Server?

Comment: Although possible, this is not advisable. Sending a message requires a Server Key, which you'll probably have to put in your Android side code in order to send the message. Note that Server keys must **always** be kept secret.

Comment: Also, how do you plan to receive these notifications in Python code? For what I know, existing libraries only allow you to send notifications, not to receive them.

Comment: Device running python code? you want to recieve notifcation on desktop/laptops? I dont think there is any recieving notification method in python, But they do offer listeners for read and write for realtime database, One way is to update the DB at the same time, and make your python script to listen to that datapath inside firebase database